# I'm looking for an airline operating flight number MYX471

Tags: air-travel, airlines

I'm looking for the airline that flew from RIX to Heraklion on May 21. Flight number - MYX471.

Comment: As it is, it has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: Would this be a fit for migration to Aviation?

Answer (score 1):

[RadarBox](https://www.radarbox24.com/data/flights/myx471) and [FlightAware](https://fr.flightaware.com/live/flight/MYX471) both say it is SmartLynx Airlines Estonia.

Comment: Well, it's even simpler than that: MYX is the IATA code of SmartLynx Airlines Estonia ;-)

Comment: @motoDrizzt -- actually, MYX is the *ICAO* code for that airline -- they are a charter airline, so they have no IATA code.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject yeah, you're obviously right, sorry :-)